# How to Parse LARGE JSON files with formating error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a bunch of large JSON files (> 500MB) which I would like to parse with the ruby script (I am trying. to parse it with YAJL gem).

I have noticed that JSON files have formatting errors such that all the files composed of "multiple" JSON objects without a proper tree-like structure or array. Below you can find how the JSON file looks like:

testfile.json:

```
{title: "Don Quixote", author: "Miguel de Cervantes", printyear: 2010}
{title: "Great Gatsby", author: "F. Scott Fitzgerald", printyear: 2014}
{title: "Ulysses", author: "James Joyce", printyear: 2010}
```

This is the script to parse file:

```
require 'yajl'
json = File.new('testfile.json', 'r')
hash = Yajl::Parser.parse(json)
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
Yajl::ParseError: Found multiple JSON objects in the stream but no block or the on_parse_complete callback was assigned to handle them.
```

I will appreciate if you can guide me on how to solve this issue.

Comment: firstly you need to properly format data into proper json format

Comment: ^ yes, even just one of these lines on its own is not valid JSON, you need to wrap keys in quotes

Comment: Would not `File.readlines.map(&method(:eval))` suffice?

Answer (score 3):

The error message you got (*"Found multiple JSON objects in the stream …"*) implies that your input contains multiple but *valid* JSON objects, so I assume your actual file looks more like this:

```
{"title":"Don Quixote","author":"Miguel de Cervantes","printyear":2010}
{"title":"Great Gatsby","author":"F. Scott Fitzgerald","printyear":2014}
{"title":"Ulysses","author":"James Joyce","printyear":2010}
```

One of YAJL's feature is to:

> Parse and encode *multiple* JSON objects to and from streams or strings continuously.

So given above input (as a file or string), you can pass a *block* to `parse` which will be called for each parsed object:

```
require 'yajl'

io = File.open('testfile.json')

Yajl::Parser.parse(io) do |book|
  puts "“#{book['title']}” by #{book['author']} (#{book['printyear']})"
end
```

Output:

```
“Don Quixote” by Miguel de Cervantes (2010)
“Great Gatsby” by F. Scott Fitzgerald (2014)
“Ulysses” by James Joyce (2010)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `JSON.parse`, beacuse the file's content is not a JSON. Each line from this file looks like a Ruby hash, so different parsing method could be used.

You should be able to parse each line by using: `YAML.load(line)`.

Also, beacuse the file is big, don't load the whole file into memory. Use [`File.foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach) to load line by line.

```rb
require 'yaml'

lines = []
File.foreach('testfile.json') do |line|
  lines << YAML.load(line)      
end
```

Comment: This falls apart if there are any multi line object like say an `Array` or `Hash` that is arranged vertically.